# the connection between Span,Linear combination and Linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

I do not understand the "connection" between said 3 terms

i.e.

z belongs to Span{u ,v ,w } , u=v-w 
does that mean z is a linear combination of w and v?

does that mean you can multiply any vector within a span by a scalar and create any other vector in said span?

or you only need 2 vectors to follow said rule

Answer (score 1):

The fact that
\begin{equation*}
z\in\mathrm{Span}\{u,v,w\}
\end{equation*}
means that there exists scalars $a,b,c$ such that
\begin{equation*}
z=au+bv+cw,
\end{equation*}
i.e., that $z$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $u$, $v$, and $w$.

Linear independence is instead defined as follows. Consider the linear combination
\begin{equation*}
au+bv+cw
\end{equation*}
where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are generic scalars. We say that $u$, $v$, and $w$ are linearly independent if such linear combination is zero if and only if $a=b=c=0$, that is, the only way to combine $u$, $v$, and $w$ and obtain zero is to pick all coefficients equal to zero. This is equivalent to saying that no vector among $u$, $v$, and $w$ can be expressed a linear combination of the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a vector space over a field of scalars, a **linear combination** from some specified subset of vectors is just a sum of scalar multiples of vectors from that subset.

- Note that you may as well assume that you always use *all* of the vectors from the specified subset, since you could always throw in the unused ones with a scalar multiplier of $0$.)

The **span** of a specified subset of vectors is the collection of ALL linear combinations of those vectors.

A specified set of vectors is **linearly independent** if none of them is a nontrivial linear combination of the others. ("Nontrivial" means we exclude the case where all the scalar multipliers are $0$.) Another way to say this is to say that the specified subset is "linearly independent" if the only linear combination that is $\vec 0$ is the trivial linear combination (all scalars must be $0$).

- Note that taking all scalar multipliers to be $0$ in a linear combination always yields the vector $\vec 0$ as a result. The specified set is linearly independent if this is the *only* way to get the vector $\vec 0$ as a result.

Answer (score 1):

The span of a vector space $S$ is any linear combination of the vectors that make up $S$, or $$S = \left \{ v_{0}, v_{1},....,v_{n} \right \}$$
and with scalars $a_{n}$
$$Span(S) = a_{0}v_{0} + a_{1}v_{1}+ .... + a_{n}v_{n}$$
A vector space $S$ is said to be linearly dependent if there are non-zero coefficients $a_{n}$ that satisfy 
$$a_{0}v_{0} + a_{1}v_{1}+ .... + a_{n}v_{n} = \vec{0}$$
which is all just a jargon filled and fancy mathematical way of saying that if you can find any linear combination of $S$ with any non-zero coefficient $a_{n}$ that sends the Span of $S$ to the zero vector $\vec{0}$ (sometimes called the trivial vector space), then $S$ is linearly dependent. If you cannot find any of these coefficients, then $S$ is linearly independent. This combines all 3 definitions. An example of this is if you are given the span of $S$ as 
$$Span(S) = \left \{ \begin{bmatrix}3\\ 1\\ 2\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}4\\ 5\\ 2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 4\\ 6\end{bmatrix}\right \}$$
Then you would have to solve the following matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4 & 0  \\ 1 &  5&  4 \\ 2 &  2&  6 \end{bmatrix}\left.\begin{matrix}\\ \\\end{matrix}\right|\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\ 0\end{bmatrix} $$
Which you would solve by row reducing and solving for the span of some coefficients that send the matrix to 0, or essentially finding the null space of the augmented matrix. An important property of linear independence is the following:

If $$S = \left \{ v_{0}, v_{1},....,v_{n} \right \}$$ is linearly independent, then
$$S = \left \{ v_{0}, v_{1},....,v_{n-1} \right \}$$ is also linearly independent.

I leave this one up to you to prove. Good luck!

Comment: How do you mean? I don't quite understand your comment.

Comment: The term of is a little bit trick for me it seems
 I look at it as a group of vectors that are created from each other using Scalars i.e (2,4) (-4,-8) 

But also (if i understood correctly) it is a group of vectors that is equal to the sum of all of the vectors while each vectors is multiplied by a scalar

Comment: Oh I see you mean the term of Span. In linear algebra, a vector space is defined by a list of axioms, or operations you can perform on the elements of a vector space (the vectors). Some axioms included are a good multiplication and addition. Because you are allowed to add and scale vectors, all vectors that can be scaled and added together in a vector space are included in the vector space itself. Hence, we can define the span of a vector space by a sequence of vectors, since we can add and scale them together to reach any other vector that is included in the vector space. Hope this helps!